# Converting text MB/GB to value

Tags: perl

I have a variable which contains a file size:

```
my $tx = "41.4 MB";
```

or

```
my $tx = "34.4 GB";
```

How do I go about converting this to a KB value. So if tx contains MB then * 1024, and if tx contains GB  then * 1024 * 1024?

Comment: It seems like you already know how to solve this, what are you specifically having trouble with ?

Comment: How do I check if it contains MB or GB in perl?  I cant just say 41.1 MB * 1024?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate out and test the units.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub size_to_kb {
    my $size = shift;
    my ($num, $units) = split ' ', $size;

    if ($units eq 'MB') {
        $num *= 1024;
    } elsif ($units eq 'GB') {
        $num *= 1024 ** 2;
    } elsif ($units ne 'KB') {
        die "Unrecognized units: $units"
    }

    return "$num KB";
}

print size_to_kb("41.4 MB"), "\n";

print size_to_kb("34.4 GB"), "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
42393.6 KB
36071014.4 KB
```

< / hand holding >